# Restrict query parameters that can be passed to asp.net mvc rest service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I have some service that I can query:

> http://localhost/myservice/data?key=value

Is there a way I can restrict the query parameters? E.g. I want to report an error if someone calls the service with unsupported parameter, e.g. I want following to fail:

http://localhost/myservice/data?key=value&anyotherparam=1

I am not sure if this is the right thing to do. However I was asked if the above scenario can be implemented so I want to give a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service ignores the `anotherparam`, honestly who cares?

And for those who care:

```
public ActionResult Data(string key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) || Request.QueryString.Count > 1)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ...
}
```

And obviously if you have to write this if over and over again across multiple actions you are better of refactoring it into a custom action filter.

Comment: So the only way is parsing the query string myself? I understand that usually you should not care about unused parameters, but there are cases when user of the API assumes that some parameter is supported when it is not. In this case parameter will be ignored, which is not always obvious to the consumer.